# What does the sentence "The element expressions in an array initializer are evaluated each time the array initializer is evaluated" mean?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was reading David Flanagan's JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, probably the fattest book for JavaScript in the world. When briefly describing array initializers, Flanagan said "The element expressions in an array initializer are evaluated each time the array initializer
is evaluated". What does this means. My practice results made me more confused:

```
var a = 50;    
var b = 70;

var array = [a+b, 50];
console.log (array [0]);  //120

a = 60;
console.log (array [0]);  //120

var other = array;
console.log (other [0]);  //120
```

I thought the result would be 130 after I change a's value to 60, because the expression is going to be re-evaluated. But it's not that. I know I am completely getting it wrong. Can someone explain what Flanagan is trying to explain in that sentence?

Comment: It wont, basically, the `array` and `a` become two values after you do the first operation...Even if you change `a`, you would need to re calculate array.

Comment: Well, first, you're interpreting the sentence backwards. "A is evaluated when B is evaluated" does not imply at all that when A changes, B does too. When the _array_ `[a+b, 50]` is evaluated, `a+b` is evaluated, yielding 120, `50` is evaluated, yielding 50, and they are placed into an array: `[120, 50]`. That array does not in any way retain a reference to `a` nor `b`, and it is not re-evaluated when `a` is re-evaluated.

Comment: Also, with `a = 60`, you're _not_ re-evaluating `a`. That would be, possibly, `a.someDestructiveMethod()` (but here, `a` is a primitive, so that wouldn't even do). What you're doing is _redefining_ the binding `a` to _another_ value `60`.

Comment: @FélixSaparelli Thanks, it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misquoted the author; what he actually said is

> The element expressions in an array *initializer* are evaluated each time the array *initializer* is evaluated.

Rather than the term "array initializer", it would be clearer, and more in line with common usage, if he said "array literal". If we adopt the common-sense interpretation of "array initializers" as meaning "initializers for an array-valued variable", then such initializers **could** be array literals, but could also be any array expression. (Having said that, it does appear that the spec uses the term "array initializer" for "array literal" in [Section 12.2.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-initializer), so the author's usage is not wrong in that technical sense.) Array literals (basically, anything of the form `[...]`) **can**, on the other hand, be used as initializers, but can also be used elsewhere.

What he appears to be trying to say is that an array literal such as

```
[a]
```

re-evaluates `a` each time it itself is re-evaluated, such as when a function is re-executed. If you think about it, that's pretty obvious. It's hard to see how it could work any other way. So the function

```
function foo(x) { return [x]; }
```

will return the array `[1]` when called as `foo(1)`, and the array `[2]` when called as `foo(2)`, because the array literal `[x]` is re-evaluated each time the function is called.

This is an entirely different issue from the one that is tripping you up, which is that

```
var a = 22;
var b = [a];
a = 42;
console.log(b);
```

does **not** change `b` to have the value `[42]`. This behavior has nothing to do with how array initializers are (re-)evaluated or their component elements are (re-)evaluated. Is has to do with how JavaScript variables and references work. The above would change the value of `b` **if** `b` were storing a dynamic reference to `a` as its element, but JavaScript has no such notion of dynamically-updatable references. To put it a different way, the `console.log(b)` line is indeed evaluating `b`, but that just returns whatever `b` already is. It does not (re-)evaluate the expression `[a]` originally used to set `b`. The fact that `b` happens to have taken on he value resulting from evaluating `[a]` is lost immediately after the statement setting the value of `b`, at which point `b` now has the value `[22]`.

Consider also the following example, which is completely analogous:

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = a + b;
a = 42;
console.log(c);
```

Here, no-one would expect the expression given as the initial value for `c` to change when the value of `a` changes later. `c` is 3, and it will always be until explicitly re-assigned. In the `console(c)` line, yes, we are "evaluating" `c`, but that is merely a matter of retrieving the value of `c`, not of re-evaluating some expression which happens to have used to assign a value to `c` in the past. There are some other declarative-style language paradigms where things might behave in that way, but not JavaScript.

Comment: Before proclaiming what is or isn't an array initialiser, you might check with the [*language specification*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-initializer). ;-)

Comment: @RobG Thanks for pointing that out. I note that in the entire spec the term "array initializer" is used exactly three times. Two are in the "array initializers" section, which then proceeds to actually define something called an "array literal", including in the name of the syntactic construct. (The third is in the JSON section.) The term "initializer" by itself, on the other hand, is used in over 100 places, all referring to the `= 1` part of a variable declaration such as `var x = 1;`. If you showed `[1]` to 100 JS programmers, 99 if not 100 would identify it as an "array literal".

Comment: @RobG Therefore, although the spec is the inerrant word of God, and you may be correct in a narrow sense that the "array initializer" is correct terminology for `[1]`, I would say that this is not common usage and quite prone to confusion. However, I will tweak my answer.

Comment: @torazaburo—ECMA-262 not perfect? Ambiguous? Ye gods! :-0 Trivia points for noticing that the spelling changed between ES5 and ECMAScript 2015 from "initialiser" to "initializer". I guess everything else was Americanised so they might as well finish the job.

Answer (score 1):

He means that when the array literal expression is ("re"-)evaluated, so will be its contents.

```
function makeArray() {
    return [a];
}
var a = 0;
console.log(makeArray()); // [0]
a = 1;
console.log(makeArray()); // [1]
```

So, nothing special actually, just default expression behaviour.

Comment: Interesting, does hoisting takes effect also in the global scope?

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Also see arrays of (object) refs: `A = {v:2}; B = [A, 50]; console.log(JSON.stringify(B)); A.v = 3; console.log(JSON.stringify(B));` will output `[{"v":2},50]` then `[{"v":3},50]` (when A is changed, so does B — not really, B doesn't change, _the A referenced by B changes_). Versus arrays of primitives: `A = 2; B = [A, 50]; console.log(JSON.stringify(B)); A = 3; console.log(JSON.stringify(B));` will output `[2,50]` then `[2,50]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you assigning the `array` to array variable and it will store that value until that variable(unless you modify that variable) goes out of scope. In the second statement you're reusing the the same array pointed to by "array" variable. Third statement is just assigning the reference to "array" variable to another variable and access the same element.

Only the first time a+b statement is evaluated and that resulting array is saved as value reference. Last statement is an example of pass by value(Javascript is always pass by value) where copy of "array" variable is created as "other", and "other" also points to same memory reference pointed by "array" variable.